# Struggling with Bean Validation within a JAX RS running in a Glassfish Container

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rs, bean-validation

I'm working on a simple Java EE Application, using Glassfish.

Everything runs fine, my Entity and Session Beans are working.

I also created some JAX RS Resources to invoke the Session Beans, which also works fine.

Now I'm struggling with Bean Validation.

Let's have a look at a little snippet:

```
@GET
@Path( "{portaluser}" )
@NotNull
public PortaluserResponse load( @PathParam( "portaluser" ) @NotBlank @Email final String strEmail )
{ ... some implementation ... }
```

My Jersey Application, which of course extends ResourceConfig looks like this:

```
public JerseyApplication()
{
    packages( PortaluserService.class.getPackage().getName() );
    register( JacksonFeature.class );
    register( ValidationConfig.class);
    property( ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true );
}
```

In my pom.xml I included following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

If I invoke the REST Service with nonsense data, the validation doesn't kick in.
Why is that? I expect to get a validation error.

I found a jersey-Sample which covers the bean validation stuff. My REST-Resource works within that project. 
The only difference is, that jersey-Sample doesn't run in Glassfish, but in a Jetty.

Can it be that jersey bean validation doesn't work when running in a Java EE container?

Would appreciate some hints.